# get information on an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I want to get information on an Assembly in my C# application. I use the following:

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

This works perfectly returning information on the calling Assembly.

I want to share this functionality with other applications, so I include this in a class in my class library.

I reference this class library in multiple applications. When I make a call to this method from my applications, it returns information on the class library and not the application. Is there a way I can alter my above code to return information on the web applications assembly while still having the code included in the class library?

Comment: You might be asking a question too low level. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having the class library being intelligent why don't you have the caller pass an `Assembly` as argument to the method? So when you call the method from within some application you would pass `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` and the method within the class library will now be able to fetch the assembly of the actual caller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you provide on top of reflections, but maybe you're abstracting a facility that doesn't need to be abstracted.  Reflections already handles this, so why not let it do its job?

But if this API gives you back some useful information (such as plugging nicely into your database, etc), then maybe your approach makes some sense.  But I still recommend that you refactor it:

- Put this code in only one shared project/assembly, and just link that project/assembly when you need to call that functionality.  Needing to [duplicate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to get your job done is considered [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).
- Take an `Assembly` object as a parameter, rather than trying to determine the *current* assembly.  This will allow more flexibility in case you come up with some code that wants to get data on a bunch of *other* assemblies, and will still allow you to pass the current assembly. (Note: Darin already made this point)